# Why does electrum wallet try to send my all bitcoins to my wallet again?

Tags: wallet, transaction-fees

Lets say my bitcoin address is A1x..
I want to send only 0.01 BTC to B1X..
but when I try to this my electrum wallet tries to this:

Input:

```
 5e2fd820...dc20cc83:9   A1x     0.04518834
8fa1efe2...906c5f6a:11   A1x     0.09476086
948d1aa1...7a5c31fa:9    A1x     0.05185725
c19d44fc...0b921636:6    A1x     0.02999874
c708c38b...aff743e8:0    A1x     0.09918895
```

Output:

```
     A1x    0.22090994
     B1X    0.10000000
```

But can't input look like this? I mean shorter for example like this?

```
B1X    0.10000000
```

or How can I stop this? I changed options but it didn't work.
**Becuase of this I have to pay 5X or 6X transactions fee
Why does electrum do this?

Comment: Whereas your question is meaningful, the offensive wording and the capital letters might prevent from getting answers. We can see this is your first post. Also you choose to argue with a well known member of the group here. I'd ask you to rephrase your question, and seek a more solution oriented approach.

Comment: shut up, if it is meaningful he or she has to answer correctly or if he/she didn't understand have to ask me politely. I am not here to lose my time or to eat -1 point because of repliers' ignorance and/or arrogance

Comment: @BarışKurt please be nice, people are trying to help you, and will be a lot more likely to help if you are :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you only have a $20 bill and a $50 bill, but you want to pay someone $1. You're going to have to use the $20 bill and get $19 back to yourself. And until you get those $19 back from your first payment, you can't use them to make other payments.

The same is true with bitcoin. Unless you happen to have an unspent output that is precisely the value you want to sent plus the transaction fee, you're going to have to form a transaction that sends some funds back to yourself.

To avoid having to wait for previous transactions to confirm, make your payments at the same time. You can find directions for how to do this in [the electrum documentation](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-do-bulk-payments-with-electrum). This will save you significantly on transactions because you won't have to make and claim as many change outputs.

Comment: I am not asking this actually this is increasing transcation fees 5x sometimes 6x **** if you don't know the answer don't reply. And what are you talking about???? Your answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @BarışKurt It sounds like you don't understand your own question then. I explained why your wallet does this, why it can't look the way you want it to, and how to work around the need to wait for confirmations from one transaction before performing another one. (Which will also save you on transaction fees.)

Comment: Like I said, still you are talking to yourself.

Comment: I explained why you are seeing what you're seeing and how to avoid it. If that doesn't answer your question, then you asked the wrong question.